# Not loading correctly in IE Compatibility view for IE7 and IE8, fine in all other browsers

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, ie8-compatibility-mode

Site loads / displays correctly in all browsers including IE9, but not when i turn on compatibility view for IE7 and IE8. On the homepage (http://www.adrtimes.com) the top boxes for the articles, news and media columns do not load in the content (using jquery to load in the content from another page) -- and I cannot figure out what the problem could be. I would greatly appreciate a point in the right direction if anyone can see what the problem might be!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

$(function(){ 

/* Home */
/* load most recent article */
$("#modulePage11493926 #LoadRecentArticles").load("/articles/category/articles .list-journal-entry-wrapper .journal-entry-wrapper:first:not(.category-video)", function(){ 
  //callback...
  $("#LoadRecentArticles .journal-entry-wrapper").wrapAll('<div class="list-journal-entry-wrapper" />');
});

/* load most recent news */
$("#modulePage11493926 #LoadRecentHotlinks").load("/articles/category/hotlinks .list-journal-entry-wrapper .journal-entry-wrapper:first:not(.category-video)", function(){ 
  //callback...
  $("#LoadRecentHotlinks .journal-entry-wrapper").wrapAll('<div class="list-journal-entry-wrapper" />');
});

/* load most recent media */
$("#modulePage11493926 #LoadRecentVideos").load("/articles/category/media .list-journal-entry-wrapper .journal-entry-wrapper:first", function(){ 
  //callback...
  $("#LoadRecentVideos .journal-entry-wrapper").wrapAll('<div class="list-journal-entry-wrapper" />');
});


}); 
-->
</script>
```

The strange thing is that the content doesnt load in on the homepage but all the rest of the jquery before and after these loading functions work fine. and sometimes when i go to one of the article pages it takes FOREVER to load and sometimes says it wont load due to a long running script. sometimes it wont say what script is causing the problem and other times it says its the jquery library script - but then when i click the stop script button the page loads fine and the jquery loads fine.

Comment: Please. Show. Code. of things that are not working. Hopefully, with error messages shown by the browser.

Comment: since i dont know what/where the problem is i have no idea what part of the code to show. the loaded content on the homepage is not loading in compatibility view, but other pages have problems as well (all related). my testing is not showing errors.

Comment: Has been working fine for two years and now not - so i assume it has something to do with the jquery library that is being referenced (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js) or some sort of update to the CMS being used, or .... something along those lines. the only recent changes have been to the AuthorBlurbs.js file and the blog posts.

Comment: I feel like im looking for a needle in a haystack! is there any chance the site loads correctly in "real" versions of IE7 and IE8 and only having problems in the simulated "compatibility mode"?

Comment: Should I try to force turn off compatibility mode?

Comment: Compatibility mode is triggered if you don't comply to standards. Use a proper doctype and validate your document using w3c tools, firebug or similar. In the end, you'd develop aiming to standards mode, NOT to compatibility mode.

Comment: it initially loads in IE 9 standards mode just fine on my computer (always starts in standards and compatibility mode is not triggered on its own) - only my client is reporting that the site is not working correctly so when i test it to try to see what his complaint is thats when i switch to compatibility mode and see the problems.

Comment: The question is: Is your client enabling by himself compatibility mode? Always test with the real browser (not just IEtester), use a virtual machine or similar... try to replicate the whole environment. To force compatibility mode off is just ignoring the real problem (if there is one)